# OpenGL - auto generation of indices / stride parameter for glDrawArrays

Tags: opengl, index-buffer

I'm rendering a grid-structure with lots of data-points (>1M). The structure of my data is in the picture.

[image: Structure of data-points]

So the content of my index buffer looks like this `0, 100, 1, 101, 2, 102, 3, 103, ...`

I'm a bit annoyed by the huge size of my index-buffer which I need to define my triangle strip. Is there a possibility to tell OpenGL to generate these indices automatically in the showed way? Or maybe some trick with glVertexAttribPointer I haven't though of?

Comment: shouldn't it start at 0 (or loop back to 101)

Comment: not that I'm aware of. you could use `glDrawArrays` without any bound attributes and read your vertex data from a sampler or image (`texelFetch`/`imageLoad`), indexed with `gl_VertexID`. It might be slower due to pulling data and cache misses, but can't be certain.

Comment: @ratchetfreak: You are right. It should start with 0!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is indeed a function for something like this: [`glDrawElementsBaseVertex`](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/GlDrawElementsBaseVertex)

so you can draw them all with:

```
for(int i=0; i < height-1; i++){
    glDrawElementsBaseVertex(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 200, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0, i*100);
}
```

the index buffer is then just: `0, 100, 1, 101, 2, 102, 3, 103,... 98, 198, 99, 199`

With some tweaking you can even use [`glMultiDrawElementsBaseVertex`](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glMultiDrawElementsBaseVertex):

```
GLsizei *count = new GLsizei[height-1];
GLvoid **indices = new GLvoid[height-1];
GLint *basevertex​ = new GLint[height-1];
for(int i = 0; i< height-1; i++){
    count[i]=200;
    indices[i]=0;
    basevertex​[i]=i*100;
}
glMultiDrawElementsBaseVertex(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, count, indices, height-1, basevertex​);
```

Comment: Isn't the question about generating the indices as opposed to rendering what's in the element array buffer?

Comment: @legends2k it's (between the lines) about reducing the size of the element array buffer which this solution allows. There's a bit of a X-Y problem when you include the last paragraph of the OP.

Comment: Aah, I see it now. Generate just the indices for one row and reuse it for all the rest of the rows. Anyway, I'm the one who +1'd this answer, since I liked the solution even otherwise before commenting.

Comment: @ratchetfreak: Hmm, that's an interesting approach. But I still have some concerns about the increase of the GL-calls. 1000-gl-calls more per drawing is a lot of work for the cpu...

Comment: @ThomasSpranger that's why I added the `glMultiDrawElementsBaseVertex` variant, and nothing is stopping you from increasing up the indexbuffer so 2 or more lines are drawn at once

Comment: @ratchetfreak: Ok, now I got it. Cool idea, much better than the current, but I still have some concerns (sorry ;)): With glMultiDrawElementsBaseVertex I'll have to copy the complete arrays on each draw-call. So there would be 3 arrays with 1000 elements to copy on every frame. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @ThomasSpranger you can pre-generate them and hold them statically, if you look carefully you'll see that they don't need to change at all between frames

Comment: @ratchetfreak: Sure, but I'll have to send them to the graphicscard on every frame. I don't think I can use a buffer for these...?

Comment: @ThomasSpranger still better than calling `glDrawElementsBaseVertex` 1000 times, honestly try to get a happy medium between index buffer size and the size of the arrays.

Comment: @ratchetfreak: Ok, I think that's definitely better than the previous solution. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @ThomasSpranger: there is also [`glMultiDrawElementsIndirect()`](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glMultiDrawElementsIndirect) from [`GL_ARB_multi_draw_indirect`](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/multi_draw_indirect.txt) which allows you to put those arrays into a buffer object and to further reduce CPU overhead with this approach.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I was able to find is to use glMultiDrawElementsIndirect. The buffer size is lots of smaller than the original one and you can pass all draw-commands with one gl-call.
Thanks to derhass for the hint!